# Denver's public transportation system

Tags: public-transport, tips-and-tricks, colorado, denver

I have a plan to attend conference at the University of Denver in March. I am also interested in getting around some attractive sites in Denver and nearby cities by using public transport or rental car.

How easy with public transport is it to get around Denver? and
How easy is it to drive in Denver?

Thank you in advance.

Satha

Comment: I live in Denver and use public transit, but without knowing which "attractive sites" youre interested in I can't easily make a recommendation. But I'll write up a general answer once I get off this airplane...

Comment: "How easy" is not a kind of question well-suited to Stack Exchange. How do you define easy? Where in Denver will you be based and where would you be traveling to? How much money do you want to spend? Some people really hate driving and will put up with a great deal to use mass transit, and others are just the opposite and will always prefer to drive in their own car. What is easy for one can be torture for the other.

Comment: OK well never mind, if the question gets reopened I'll finish my answer then. TLDR is that public transit is very easy to use, accessible, and on time -- especially in comparison with cities like Baltimore. Bit more on the pricy side. None of this is opinion based since, well, prices are numbers and you don't get a discount cus you think it's pricy. ;)

Comment: Also there's a light rail stop at the University of Denver, so if you're staying in central downtown or the suburbs, you just get yourself a rail pass. You can currently buy a day pass from the machines at the light rail stops -- you'll need a regional pass if you're going from DU to central downtown since that's three fare zones -- and a full fare will cost you $10.

Comment: There is a commuter train from the airport to Union Station in central downtown; it runs every 15 minutes. From Union Station you can catch the bus rapid transit to Boulder -- runs every 15 minutes as well during the day, I think a little less often on weekends. During the work week there's a twice-daily bus rapid transit connection between Colorado Springs and Denver (direct connection, no stops; if the schedule doesn't align consider driving or flying.)

Comment: Golden, CO, where the Coors factory is (they have a free tour with free samples) is connected to Denver either by the light rail -- catch the W from Union Station, you'll need a regional fare -- or take the 16L bus from Civic Center (across from the capital.) The bus will cost less, currently $2.25 (local fare), and possibly be faster, but it does go down a rather sketchy stretch of Colfax Avenue. I don't recommend riding it after dark.

Comment: Fares are here: http://www.rtd-denver.com/Fares.shtml . Note they will change in early January. The day pass might be replaced by a 3-hour ticket, but I can't confirm yet. I recommend downloading the RTD app from the Google Play or Apple App Store instead. Otherwise you can buy 10-ride ticket booklets from the RTD ticket kiosks in Union Station (the underground bus concourse) or any King Soopers or Safeway supermarket (go to the service desk). Remember to validate your ticket *before* getting on the light rail if you buy a ticket book.

Comment: If you're staying downtown, you will pay through the nose for parking. I-25 -- which would be how you get to DU otherwise -- becomes a parking lot during rush hour. I wave at those poor souls from the train on my daily commute. ;) Definitely do not recommend trying to drive I-25 during rush hour or during any kind of precipitation because Denver drivers do *not* do precipitation well. Even snow.

Comment: ^ That's the tl;dr of what my answer would be, without the pictures or the warnings of local scams or mentions of the scooters and bikes and other stuff that makes driving in Denver exciting. Oh and if you do drive, please remember that the train has the right of way if only because it's really really big and really cannot stop all that quickly. (I am tired of cars running into my train.)

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable advice Roddy of the Frozen Peas. I have booked my accommodation at La Quinta Inn Denver Hotel where is located very close to the University.                                                        
Actually, I would prefer to use public transport to get around Denver. However, I am also interested in visiting Rocky Mountain and renting a car might be a good option to get to the farther reaches of attractive sites.